# Fallo en la conversión de un XML a objeto java con JAXB

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

Estoy probando convertir el siguiente archivo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<question id="1">
    <answer>
        <answername>java is a programming language</answername>
        <id>101</id>
        <postedby>ravi</postedby>
    </answer>
    <answer>
        <answername>java is a platform</answername>
        <id>102</id>
        <postedby>john</postedby>
    </answer>
    <questionname>What is java?</questionname>
</question>
```

al objeto de java Question:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Question {

    private int id;
    private ArrayList<Answer> answers;
    private String questionname;

    public Question() {
    }

    public Question(int id, ArrayList<Answer> answers, String questionname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.questionname = questionname;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ArrayList<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(ArrayList<Answer> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public String getQuestionname() {
        return questionname;
    }

    public void setQuestionname(String questionname) {
        this.questionname = questionname;
    }

}
```

Aquí detallo también la clase del objeto Answer:

```
public class Answer {

    private int id;
    private String answername;
    private String postedby;

    public Answer() {
    }

    public Answer(int id, String answername, String postedby) {
        this.id = id;
        this.answername = answername;
        this.postedby = postedby;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAnswername() {
        return answername;
    }

    public void setAnswername(String answername) {
        this.answername = answername;
    }

    public String getPostedby() {
        return postedby;
    }

    public void setPostedby(String postedby) {
        this.postedby = postedby;
    }

}
```

Para hacer la conversión creé la siguiente clase:

```
    import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class App {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("question.xml");
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Question.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Question question = (Question) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            
            
            System.out.println(question.getAnswers().get(0).getAnswername());
            
            
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el método main, me tira el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at App.main(App.java:17)

La línea 17 se refiere a esta:

```
System.out.println(question.getAnswers().get(0).getAnswername());
```

**Resúmen y consulta:** Este ejemplo lo saqué del siguiente tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jB_3r_Cz9Ro&t=812s . Hice todos los pasos que allí aparecen, así que el código no debería estar mal, pero al correrlo a mi si me tira un error que en el tutorial no. Estoy usando Eclipse Photon como entorno de desarrollo, JavaSE-1.8 para mi proyecto. No importé explícitamente ninguna librería, y Eclipse no tuvo problemas para reconocer las anotaciones. Me pregunto qué está mal entonces, cómo reconocer si hay alguna incompatibilidad entre versiones y cómo corregirla? Alguien me puede ayudar?

---

Gracias ya lo pude resolver, el problema era que en el objeto Question escribí que la variable que recibía la informacion de esas etiquetas era "answers" en vez de "answer" que es como le había puesto a cada una de las etiquetas.

Comment: yo veo que tu clase answer podría tener la anotación  @XmlRootElement(name="answer") en caso de que tus bindigs fueran por campos y no por métodos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si añades la anotación

```
@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "answer", type = Answer.class))
public ArrayList<Answer> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}
```

creo que tu programa va a funcionar.